# Broken Ubuntu Release after crash during upgrade

Tags: ubuntu, installation, crash, ubuntu-22.04

I was upgrading my computer from Ubuntu 20.04 to Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS. During the upgrade, my internet stopped working, and I received a Python error message, which I unfortunately did not record. My desktop was in a degraded state, so I restarted it. After restart, I can no longer reach the normal desktop interface, only being able to boot into a text-only console. The text-only console says that my Ubuntu version is still 20.04. The internet is still non-functional, either via WiFi or wired connection.

What should I do to resolve this problem and get my Ubuntu installation working again? What other information should I supply? I would prefer not to have to re-install from scratch, but I can do that if it is necessary.

Comment: Try this article 3rd major bullet down   ......   https://askubuntu.com/questions/249135/booting-issues-after-crash-during-update

Comment: @John Because I do not have internet access, that bullet will not work.

Comment: There is nothing you can do without internet so it does look like you may have to install from scractch.

Comment: @John Thanks, I figured that might be the case. I'll leave the question open in case anyone else has alternatives.

Comment: Or revert to your last disk image, which one should make frequently, and certainly before a major upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

> The text-only console says that my Ubuntu version is still 20.04. The
> internet is still non-functional, either via WiFi or wired connection.

The generally useful article I found was here ( assumes you do not have a backup prior to the upgrade):

[Ubuntu Crash](https://askubuntu.com/questions/249135/booting-issues-after-crash-during-update)

If it crashed during an update, you're in deep trouble. At this point, you have a few options:

```
Reinstall, lose everything. (Easiest. I have done this myself a few times ;)

Back up everything, reinstall. (Medium, requires a bit of linux knowledge.)

Attempt to repair your current installation. (medium, requires a lot of time. May not work.)
```

Without internet, and in view of the 3rd major point in the article where you need internet, there is not much you can do (true for almost any modern operating system).

So you will have to install from scratch.

Answer (score 0):

What follows below might not be something for a Linux novice. But a user with some insight into how things work may well succeed (at least to some degree), maybe even learn something new in the process of trying.

1. Save your files.
   a. Use a "Install media", that is, create what yo need to actually install Ubuntu again.
   b. boot that media, select "Try ubuntu"
   c. use the tools at hand to investigate what you have avilable; I would expect e.g. /home/ to be accessible after mounting the corresponding partition (e.g. your normal `/` or `/home`) by that enabling to read out the data from your /home/USERNAME/ folder.
   d. copy out the data to e.g. an external USB(?)-disk.
   e. create copies of your settings files, they often reside in folders with an initial `.` in the name, in /home/USERNAME/ - Natilus / gmome-files reveals these if you press <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>. The same is revealed by using `ls -A` at the Terminal/Shell/Bash prompt.
   f. Note that some files e.g. in `/etc/`and `/boot` also might have content to help succeed with a "full" recovery; if you e.g. reinstall.
2. Attempt to repair. This might mean running recovery mode from the damaged disk. There; run the fsck, activate internet and root prompt options.
   ***Note that you might need to backup files (before any repair attempts) also in this "mode", e.g. with RAID, LUKS and other types of media active.** These might not be EASILY accessible otherwise!*
   Assuming internet is available; at the root prompt run `apt-get update` and then look into `man apt-get` and take note of options that may help;
   e.g. `install --reinstall`, `--fix-broken`, `--fix-missing` for starters. Use `apt-get ...`  with these options, then attempt `apt-get upgrade` and `apt-get dist-upgrade` - possibly make new choices depending on what result you get.
3. The last alternative; use the install media you created in 1. and run the installation process, maybe leaving the original /home as is - as a place to restore files from.

*Note that a release-to-release upgrade is likely to succeed best with "no extra" installed software compared to a "just installed" Ubuntu. Any single added software package can be seen as a likely "threat" to a successful upgrade, depending on the complexity of that installation.*

**Helpful command hints**
`lsblk -ap` - will display a list of disks and partitions,
and also pinpoint where each is mounted, if so.
`mount device /mnt` - make "device" be available for reading at least.
Note: "device" is normally e.g. "/dev/sda1", from a "part"-line displayed by lsblk.
`umount device` or `umount /mnt` - the reverse of mount,
i.e. finalize any write operations - so a removable media can be removed with intact content.
`rsync -av _from_ _to_` - "backup" files.
`chown user:user /mnt` - make /mnt dir be owned by user.
Might be necessary on an just mounted external disk, which hasn't been used before this.
`ifconfig -a` - display available/possible `ínternet` interfaces and their status.
`ifconfig interface up` - attempt to bring up an internet connection.
"interface" is from the leftmost column of ifconfig -a, without the `:`.
`ifconfig interface down` - the reverse from above.
Toggling down then up, might help with "flaky" connections.

Note: `sudo`  prepended to the above, is -or might be- necessary when not at the root prompt. Exceptions; lsblk and rsync depending on situation.